# Upgrading from Windows CE 6.0 to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, windows-ce

I was wondering if it was possible to use a USB drive (as in, boot from USB) to upgrade from Windows CE 6.0 up to Windows 7. I have searched online for a solution, but to no avail. I currently have a "Wireless Book", made in China, running Windows CE 6.0, and currently using a flash drive with Windows 7 on it (made using Windows USB DVD Download tool). Thank you!

Comment: What are the specifications of the computer (processor/RAM/disk size)? I'm curious if it even meets the minimum system requirements for Windows 7.

Comment: First you'd need to know if device drivers exist for the "Wireless Book" device package. The usual answer is "You don't" as these items usually weren't even as powerful as the current Android tablets out there and like Android tablets don't provide an OS hardware/BIOS environment in which full a full Windows OS install will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible! The first problem is the minimum hardware requirements to install windows 7. You can check [Windows 7 system requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements) (also below) where you will understand it is impossible for the range of devices using Windows CE 6.0.

> - 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor
> - 1 gigabyte (GB) RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB RAM (64-bit)
> - 16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
> - DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver

An embedded device must meet the following requirements to run Windows Embedded Standard 7 per [Requirements for an Embedded Device (Standard 7 SP1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793769.aspx). (also below)

> - 1 GHz x86 or amd64 processor with 900 mhz speed or equivalent
> - 512 MB of system memory (1GB recommended for amd64)
> - 1 GB free space on hard disk drive (HDD) or flash-based Solid State Drive (SSD) (4 GB recommended)
>   At least one of the following bootable media types:
> - Bootable DVD-ROM drive
> - Bootable USB 2.0 port and a USB Flash Drive (UFD) with 4 GB of free space, or access to a local network
>
> BIOS Supporting Windows Preinstallation Environment (Windows PE) 3.0

Also, another problem is the hardware architecture and CPU architecture. Check out [Minimum Requirements for a Windows CE Board Support Package](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/2/672327A4-CACD-4B9E-9C40-CB5223CB8F3D/WINCE_Min_Requirements_BSP.pdf) (pdf link. you can see some of the points below) and [Windows Embedded CE 6.0 article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded_CE_6.0), so you can understand better how the system works, and therefore the machines that work on it.

CPU Requirements for Windows CE:

> - Windows CE-supported architecture (MIPS, X86, ARM, SH)
> - Memory management unit capable of 32-bit virtual memory (4GB)
> - 1MB of contiguous physical SDRAM

Comment: External links can disappear or be unavailable, in which case your answer would just be that it won't work. A much better answer would be to include the key information from the links so the links serve as just attribution and further reading.  You can just paraphrase or list the key points, or copy and paste relevant sections.  Those kinds of authoritative and complete answers tend to get upvoted on SU.

Comment: Those external links are from Microsoft and Wikipedia. If those links disappear, then what can I say for the importance of this post.
And, by the way, I won't add any paragraph, since that would be to copy and entire text, and also a list full of details which will make it even more impossible to understand things.

Comment: Those links change more than you might expect.  They also can be down when the person wants to use them.  But the point on this question is that you're mainly talking about lists of requirements, which can be simple lists (processor type, minimum RAM, etc.).  The answer doesn't need to go into a discussion of each requirement.  It makes the answer self-contained rather than a reading list if someone wants to get even the key points.  It's a little more work to create those kinds of answers, but they tend to get upvoted.  That's a way to build rep.

Comment: Okay, I will try to edit it as best as I can. It is true that if those links disappear, than the answer does not explain anything.

Comment: It is done!! :D